# php for loop from array stops after 3 loops

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, echo

I have an array that looks like this.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => MDT 2920 P
        [1] => MDT 1210 P
        [2] => MDT 939 P
        [3] => MDT 1760 P
        [4] => PDT 23800 P
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => MDT
        [1] => MDT
        [2] => MDT
        [3] => MDT
        [4] => PDT
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 2920
        [1] => 1210
        [2] => 939
        [3] => 1760
        [4] => 23800
    )
)
```

I want to loop through array in the first key of [2] and echo all the values.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($nt); $i++)
{
    echo $nt[2][$i];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

this works,  but stops after three loops and the output looks like this:

```
2920
1210
939
```

I am expecting -- hoping for this:

```
2920
1210
939
1760
23800
```

I don't understand why it is stopping. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($nt); $i++)
```

You are counting the elements of $nt (which are 3), but you want to access the elements of $nt[2] (which are 5). Thus, you need to change the above line to:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($nt[2]); $i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use foreach loop:

```
   foreach ( $array[2] as $value ) {
        echo $value;
        echo "<br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($nt); $i++)
```

is the cuplrit

you should be using

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($nt[2]); $i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$number=array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach($number as $n)
{   
echo "value is $n <br>";
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.